# android notification log history

Tags: logging, notifications

Hi there is there any way I could view history of the notification log file. I tried using andriod sdk ( db shell logcat > log.txt ) but does not get the log i wanted.

For example, if a contact join viber. You will receive a notification of the contact joining viber. Im trying to get the history of this log.

Many many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can observe notification with [AccessibilityService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html).

But you can´t go to history, you have to observe, save to your database and then you have to use own history...